# can my phone company still track what i search useing my data

Tags: anonymity

I have just found out about the wonderful world of Tor. I have it on my PC, but my question is: Can my internet company and/or phone service see what I'm searching? I understand that it is encrypted but what can they see  and if they can would a company just randomly say "oh he is encrypted lets find out what he is doing?" Also I have an Android LG K7 non rooted. What good apps are there that will help secure my phone?

Answer (score 1):

The point of your communications being *encrypted* is that your ISP *cannot* see what you are doing. Your data is encrypted using cryptographic keys that only you and the Tor network know.

Your ISP would be able to tell, if they cared to look, that you are in fact using Tor. But they would not be able to see what you're using it for. Chances are, they will never care to look.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they can even mangle and censor your data usage: the "exit node: for your connection is your *phone*, and it's logged in and routed through *their* network.

Comment: So you're saying Tor doesn't do its job.

Comment: @SuperSluether as it asked: the ISP/"company" **can** say that *it's encrypted* and they **can** try *"lets find out what he is doing"*. And - yes - ISP can censor and/or mangle the Tor traffic they see. That's what the pluggable transports are for. I don't say that they will 100% succeed in MitMing your HTTPS and will be able to see the contents, but blocking is a form of censorship by mangling network path